# What are some good natural language parsing tools for Perl?

Tags: perl, nlp

I've heard that Perl is used a lot for NLP, but I can't find almost any good NLP tools for Perl. What are some good Perl NLP tools/resources? Python has NLTK. Java has OpenNLP. Does Perl have anything similar?

This is really a general question, but if someone could also specifically address chunking and POS-tagging, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Natural Language Processing](http://perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?natural_language_processing) page on the [perl5 wiki](http://perlfoundation.org/perl5/).

Comment: These links are now dead.

Comment: @Phil Mitchell - Socialtext host the Perl wiki.  The Perl6 wiki still works fine (http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl6).  So it maybe just temporary issue with Perl5 wiki?  Unfortunately archive.org doesn't seem to save these pages so we just have to wait till Socialtext fix the issue :(

Comment: Links are still dead. Please update your answer. :)

Comment: @coder123 - The linked perl5 wiki site and all its pages are no more, has ceased to be, bereft of life and it rests in peace.  It is (at this point in time) an ex-site!   If a resurrection occurs or should pages reincarnate in another form elsewhere on the web then I, you, we or anyone here can update this (wiki) answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of good NLP-related Perl modules, so you can pick a good set of tools for your task.

However, I think there's not a toolkit such as NLTK or OpenNLP in Perl. Let's see if someone else proves me wrong ;)

Just an example or an interesting Perl module for NLP: [WordNet::Similarity](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WordNet-Similarity/).

With respect POS tagging, there is [Lingua::EN::Tagger](http://search.cpan.org/~acoburn/Lingua-EN-Tagger/Tagger.pm), but I have no idea if it is any good.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the ones smmv mentioned, there's also [Lingua-BrillTagger](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-BrillTagger/). No idea how useful it is here either :)

Answer (score 2):

[Freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/) is a suite of language analysis tools (for multiple languages) that has a decent perl API built in.